# Form ice from water in a non-deformable, completely sealed box

Tags: water, phase

Suppose that I put some water in a **non-deformable**, **completely sealed box**, in a way that all the space is occupied by water, and reduce the temperature to transform water to ice.

Since ice takes more space than water, what would happen to the water and to the box?

Comment: Your non-deformable box stands a decent chance of being deformed. Other than that, water may postpone the transformation.